# React PWA Service Worker works locally, but not when hosted on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, netlify

I'm trying to learn more about PWA Service Workers and wanted to implement that feature on this personal project site I'm working on. When I run Google's Lighthouse on Localhost the `start_url passes and responds with a 200 offline and registers a service worker.`

However, when I push the changes to Github which I'm hosting on Netlify and run the same Lighthouse test, I get: `start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline. Timed out waiting for start_url to respond. Does not register a service worker that controls page.`

This is the script I have in the index.html:

```
 <!-- PWA SERVICE WORKER SCRIPT -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(registration) {
          console.log('Worker registration successful', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log('Worker registration failed', err);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
    }
  </script>
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Arc-teryx",
  "name": "Arc-teryx using Contentful/Graphql",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Here is my worker.js file in public folder:

```
let CACHE_NAME = "Arc-teryx";
let urlsToCache = ["/", "/completed"];

// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("Opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      // Cache hit - return response
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});

// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  let cacheWhitelist = ["Arc-teryx"];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Can anyone see what I may be doing incorrectly and point me in the right direction for a fix?

Link to the [Repo](https://github.com/danlubbers/arcteryx-graphql)

Netlify link: [Project](https://zealous-goldwasser-a29aec.netlify.app)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Amazing how I've been trying to figure this out for awhile and as soon as I post it, I figured it out 30min later.

Anyways, if this helps anyone else out there who might be having a similar issue, this was my fix.

I changed the `let urlsToCache = ["/", "/completed"];` to `let urlsToCache = ["/"]` in the worker.js file
and the `"start_url": "."` to `"start_url": "/"` in the manifest.json